# Hamiltonian, Unitary and Matrices Exponential

Tags: physics

[image]

Suppose I can write my Hamiltonian as above. $J_x, J_y, J_z$ and $Q$, etc. are operators.

It is obvious that I can add the terms as I want: I can add $J_x + J_y + J_z + ...$ or $J_y + J_x + J_z ...$ or etc.

From my Hamiltonian, I can get a unitary operator. Since it is exponential, what I figured out is that I can use Lie-Trotter Product Formula,

[image]

But since $J_x$ and $J_y$ and $J_z$ do not commute, then the operators' sequence matter. So now my Hamiltonian gives different unitary operator as I add the operators differently.

I am confused because when viewing Hamiltonian, I can just add the operators I want, but when it comes to unitary operator, I cannot.

What is right?

Comment: Look up the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula.

Comment: You do not seem to actually *know* what the Lie-Trotter formula is. In any case, if the operators are hermitian, your *T* is unitary, and so is any other rearrangement of the factors. What is your question?